# Given a 4d tensor for time series predicition

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, convolutional-neural-network, time

I have multiple time series datasets, which i want to train to an lstm model.
The shape of the training data is (735,2,5,4). 735 are the time steps, 2 are the two time Series datasets, 5 are the sliding windows and 4 are features.

How can i train an lstm model with a 4d tensor.